# programmatically obtaining a list of vmware guests

Tags: vmware-esxi, scripting

Is there a way to programmatically (that is write a small c app or better yet a ruby or perl script) to obtain a list of all of the guests (and also details about the guests) from a VMWare Infrastructure?

Thanks,
Matt Delves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of options [HERE](http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/sdk_pubs.html)

Comment: This is a really poor answer. A link to paywalled documentation is not very useful.

Comment: @Thismatters This is a really poor comment, hardly surprising given you've been on this site two day and can't possibly understand its workings and history yet. Not only is it EIGHT YEARS since I posted this but also perhaps VMware may have made this 'paywalled' without contacting me personally to tell me to update this specific link - either way it's a link to the documentation, just because you're using their free product doesn't mean it ceases to answer the question, it just means you're not happy that the world hasn't been handed to you on a plate.

Comment: This is a really poor flamewar, hardly surprising. The quality and longevity of StackExchange answers is dependent on *not* simply linking to a resource and saying "Hope this helps", but instead to *actually answer the question asked*. A link to the documentation is no better than a google search would provide, so really what did your really poor answer contribute in its EIGHT YEAR lifespan?

Comment: What paywall? To VMware's credit, that eight year old link is actually still quite valid and drilling in a few clicks gets me right to anonymously accessible HTML docs for the Perl API, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work well. When invoking this perl script you will need to specify the server (`server_fqdn:port#`) along with the username and password (e.g. `$ perl listVMS --server 1.1.1.1:333 --username "whatever\user" --password "s0m3p4ss"`)

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../";

use VMware::VIRuntime;
use AppUtil::HostUtil;
use AppUtil::VMUtil;

use Data::Dumper;

use Getopt::Long qw( :config no_ignore_case pass_through );

Opts::parse('pass_through');
$server     = Opts::get_option('server');
$username   = Opts::get_option('username');
$password   = Opts::get_option('password');

$service_url = "https://".$server."/sdk/vimService";

Util::connect();

Vim::login(service_url => $service_url, user_name => $username, password => $password);

# This gets all the host systems
my $host_views = Vim::find_entity_views(view_type => 'HostSystem', properties => [ 'summary', 'hardware', 'name' ]); 

foreach my $host (@$host_views) {
    $hostname = $host->name;

    my $host_view = Vim::find_entity_view(view_type => 'HostSystem', filter => { name => $host->name } );

    # This gets all the vms running on a the host system
    my $vm_views = Vim::find_entity_views(view_type => 'VirtualMachine', begin_entity => $host_view, properties => ['summary','name']);

    print "HostSystem '$hostname' has the following virtual guests\n";
    foreach my $vm (@$vm_views) 
    {
        my $vmName = $vm->name;
        print "\t$vmName\n";
    }

} 
Util::disconnect();
```